# How to handle "ReorderableListView.builder" in Android Build?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, build

I'm trying to build a ReorderableListView.builder but in the release build on Android
there's a problem.

Newly created items are not displayed one below the other, instead there are placed on top of each other like a stack, so that only the newest is visible. When you move the items, they seem to be there, but they are invisible.

I don't have this problem during debugging, only in release or profile build.
And also only with a ReorderableListView, a normal ListView works fine.

Widget:

```
child: BlocBuilder<HuntingCubit, HuntingState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return Theme(
                    data: ThemeData(
                      canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
                      shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                      onReorderStart: (index) =>
                          context.read<HuntingCubit>().listIsOrdering(state.huntingList[index].id),
                      onReorderEnd: (index) => context.read<HuntingCubit>().listIsNotOrdering(),
                      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                        if (state.selectedHunt?.id == state.huntingList[oldIndex].id) {
                          context.read<HuntingCubit>().selectHunt(state.huntingList[oldIndex].id);
                        }
                        context.read<HuntingCubit>().reorderHunt(oldIndex, newIndex);
                      },
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: state.huntingList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Dismissible(
                          key: Key(state.huntingList[index].toString()),
                          onDismissed: (direction) {
                            // context.read<InactivityManagerCubit>().initTimer();
                          },
                          confirmDismiss: (direction) => showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (_) {
                              final targetHunt = state.huntingList[index];
                              final selectedHunt = context.watch<HuntingCubit>().state.selectedHunt;
                              return Alert(
                                icon: Icons.close,
                                iconColor: Colors.red.shade900,
                                title: 'Warnung',
                                titleColor: Colors.red.shade900,
                                content: RichText(
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                    text: 'Möchtest du die Hunt nach ',
                                    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                                    children: <TextSpan>[
                                      TextSpan(
                                          text: state.huntingList[index].pokemon.name,
                                          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      const TextSpan(text: ' wirklich aufgeben und löschen?'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                functions: [
                                  () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                  () {
                                    if (selectedHunt != null) {
                                      log('SelectedHuntId = ${selectedHunt.id} - huntId = ${targetHunt.id}');
                                      if (selectedHunt.id == targetHunt.id) {
                                        context.read<HuntingTimerCubit>().pauseTimer1();
                                        context.read<HuntingCubit>().saveDuration(
                                            context.read<HuntingCubit>().state.selectedHunt!.id,
                                            context.read<HuntingTimerCubit>().state.timer1Duration);
                                        context.read<HuntingTimerCubit>().resetTimer1();
                                      }
                                    }
                                    context.read<HuntingCubit>().removeHunt(targetHunt.id);
                                    log('state: ${BlocProvider.of<HuntingCubit>(context).state.selectedHunt}');
                                    context.read<HuntingCubit>().removeHunt(state.huntingList[index].id);
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                ],
                                actionNames: ['Nein', 'Ja'],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          child: HuntingCard(
                            hunt: state.huntingList[index],
                          ),
                        );
                        // BlocProvider.of<HuntingCubit>(context).removeHunt(state.huntingList[index].id);
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Functions:

```
void reorderHunt(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    final List<Hunt> newHuntingList = List.from(state.huntingList);

    final Hunt oldHunt = newHuntingList.removeAt(oldIndex);
    if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
      newIndex -= 1;
    }
    newHuntingList.insert(newIndex, oldHunt);
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        huntingList: newHuntingList,
        selectedHunt: state.selectedHunt,
      ),
    );
  }

  listIsOrdering(int id) {
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        huntToSort: id,
      ),
    );
  }

  listIsNotOrdering() {
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        huntToSort: null,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All right, i found the error myself^^

It was the key in the "Dismissible" respectively the one that compares the item and the index.
I first had a normal Key as String. This did not cause any problems during debugging. But in the release build it seems to need a ValueKey as int.

This fixed my problem.
I'll leave this post open in case who stumbles over the same error :)